# Curl - Variable with new lines - Illegal unquoted character code10

Tags: jenkins, curl

How to upload variable containing  new lines via curl? I get the error `Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string`

The jenkins script section reads the variable from file which has new lines.

```
                script {
                    FPR_LOW = readFile('fpr_low.txt');
                }
```

curl tries to use variable in body.

```
                sh """ curl -u username:password-X POST \
                          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                          --url 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/rest/api/2/issue/${env.TASK_KEY}/comment' \
                          -d '{ "body": "${FPR_LOW}"}'
                """
```

Then I get the following error:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -u username:password -X POST -H Content-Type: application/json --url http://10.10.10.10:8080/rest/api/2/issue/abc-111/comment -d { "body": "4 issues of 4 matched search query.

Issue counts by category:

 "J2EE Bad Practices: Leftover Debug Code" => 1 Issues
     ApiApplication.java:23 (Structural)
 "Poor Error Handling: Overly Broad Throws" => 3 Issues
     controller/BanksController.java:27 (Structural)
     controller/BanksController.java:40 (Structural)
     controller/BanksController.java:51 (Structural)

Total for all categories => 4 Issues

"}
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   669    0   230  100   439   7419  14161 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21580
{"errorMessages":["Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@7925a1f4; line: 1, column: 48]"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the specified Content-Type, the argument to CURL parameter `-d` must be a JSON-encoded string.

A simple way to do this is using the [`JsonOutput`](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_jsonoutput) class:

```
sh ''' curl -u username:password-X POST \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          --url 'http://10.10.10.10:8080/rest/api/2/issue/$TASK_KEY/comment' \
          -d ''' + "'" + groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([ body: FPR_LOW ]) + "'"
```

Note that I have replaced triple-double-quoted string by triple-single-quoted string to avoid a possible [code injection security issue](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/automating-with-jenkinsfile/string-interpolation#_injection_via_interpolation) if `TASK_KEY` variable could be user input. This is fixed by resolving the variable in the shell code instead of doing it through Groovy string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
stage('Send comment to BitBucket') {
  steps {
    script {
      def tfplan = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(readFile(file: 'tfplan.txt'))

      withCredentials([
        usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'ADMIN', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
          sh """
          curl -k -X POST -u '${TOKEN}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"text\":${tfplan}}' https://{SERVER}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{PROJECT}/repos/{REPO}/pull-requests/{NUMBER}/comments
          """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

worked in my case