# Convert bash variable into JSON string using JQ

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I have a bash variable `FPR_LOW` which is a multiline content. I want to convert this variable into JSON string so it can be used with curl.

output of variable: echo $FPR_LOW

```
Issue counts by category:

 "J2EE Bad Practices: Leftover Debug Code" => 1 Issues
     ApiApplication.java:23 (Structural)
 "Poor Error Handling: Overly Broad Throws" => 3 Issues
     controller/BanksController.java:27 (Structural)
     controller/BanksController.java:40 (Structural)
     controller/BanksController.java:51 (Structural)
```

How can I convert this variable into a JSON string using jq so there is no issue when uploading through curl body?

`curl ....  -d '{ "body": \'${JSON_FPR_LOW}\' }'`

Comment: Using double quotes allows variable interpolation `curl ....  -d "{ \"body\": \"${JSON_FPR_LOW}\" }"` should be a reasonable start. However, use "proper" tools (e.g. `jq`) for secure interpolation

Comment: I tried double quotes. I get unquoted error. Is there  a way to convert to json?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325558/curl-variable-with-new-lines-illegal-unquoted-character-code10

Comment: The [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) command makes this trivial: `curl ... -d "$(jo body="$FPR_LOW")"`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install anything on the server. Is there any other way or convert it using jq?

Comment: `-d "$(jq --arg b "$FPR_LOW" '{body: $b}')`. It's only slightly less trivial than with `jo`.

Comment: Are you missing a qoute?