# Convert mutliline shell variable to JSON string

Tags: shell, jq

How can I convert a multiline variable with special characters into a JSON string using JQ?

```
$ echo $FPR_LOW
4 issues of 4 matched search query.

Issue counts by category:

 J2EE Bad Practices: Leftover Debug Code => 1 Issues
     ApiApplication.java:23 (Structural)
 Poor Error Handling: Overly Broad Throws => 3 Issues
     controller/BanksController.java:27 (Structural)
     controller/BanksController.java:40 (Structural)
     controller/BanksController.java:51 (Structural)
```

The above string variable should be a single JSON string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bash variable into JSON string using JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325868/convert-bash-variable-into-json-string-using-jq)

Answer (score 2):

Pass the value as a `jq` variable (and tell it not to expect input):

```sh
jq -n --arg fpr "$FPR_LOW" '$fpr'
```